# Why does Unity sprite editor reduce the resolution of my sprites?

Tags: unity, sprites

I have a PNG file ([taken from here](https://github.com/jahshuwaa/u4graphics/blob/master/32x32x24/shapes.png)) with tiles that look like this:

[image]

Each tile is 32x32 pixels. I tried to use Unity's Sprite Editor to slice them into individual tiles. Here are the settings I used:

[image]

After I clicked "apply", the sprite resolution became much lower - about 8x8:

[image]

What did I do wrong? How can I correctly slice the PNG file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I download your image, it is not 32x256 but 246x1953. If you cut it on 32x32 chunks, it would make small looking images. The preview agrees with that

[image]

If you don't want to do the math, use the Grid by Cell count option. If all your other assets are in a 32x32 chunks, you can adjust with the Pixels per Unit to get the sprite to the overall same size.

The second image has a different problem. The size is 32x8192, the default size for images is 2048. Once you change it in the import settings of the sprite, when you go to the slize screen it looks normal again.

[image]

Comment: Actually, the image is from here: https://github.com/jahshuwaa/u4graphics/blob/master/32x32x24/shapes.png so it is really 32x32 (I uploaded a part of it to the post, but IMGUR probably scaled it up).

Comment: The second solution worked. Thanks a lot!